# SaltStack - Beacons not monitoring the files

Tags: salt-stack, salt-cloud

For some reason I can't get the beacons working.. I can send the event manually using this command from minion `salt-call event.send salt/beacon/*/inotify//etc/hosts` and I see the event in the master.

But if I modify the `/etc/hosts` or delete it the event doesn't fire automatically.

I've installed `python3-pyinotify` on the minion. Any idea why beacons aren't monitoring the `/etc/hosts` file?

In the minion logs I see this:

```
2022-11-17 12:39:14,299 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:14,300 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
2022-11-17 12:39:15,300 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:15,300 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
2022-11-17 12:39:16,300 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:16,301 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
2022-11-17 12:39:17,300 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:17,301 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
2022-11-17 12:39:18,300 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:18,301 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
2022-11-17 12:39:19,300 [salt.beacons     :89  ][WARNING ][14639] No validate function found for inotify, running basic beacon validation.
2022-11-17 12:39:19,301 [salt.beacons     :167 ][WARNING ][14639] Unable to process beacon inotify
```

`/etc/salt/minion.d/beacons.conf:`

```
beacons:
  inotify:
    - files:
        /etc/hosts:
          mask:
            - modify
    - disable_during_state_run: True
```

`master reactor.conf:`

```
reactor:
  - salt/beacon/*/inotify//etc/hosts:
      - /srv/salt/reactor/etc_hosts.sls
```

`/srv/salt/reactor/etc_hosts.sls:`

```
revert_etc_hosts:
  local.state.sls:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
    - arg:
      - formula.etc_hosts
```

Here is the minion conf:

```
grains:
  salt-cloud:
    driver: ec2
    profile: base_ec2_micro_ubuntu
    provider: ec2-ap-south-1-public:ec2
hash_type: sha256
id: dev-web
log_level: info
master: 10.10.10.10
default_include: minion.d/*.conf
```

Comment: If you're using onedir then dependencies must be installed with `salt-pip`

Comment: What's onedir? also how can I install salt-pip on other machines? I can't find the package named salt-pip

Comment: I used bootstrap script to setup masters and minions are configured automatically during salt-cloud provisioning

Comment: https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/install-guide/en/latest/topics/upgrade-to-onedir.html

Comment: Thank you that was the issue. I had to install pyinotify from master. `salt 'dev-web' pip.install pyinotify`. How can I automate this so every new minion get pyinotify installed via pip? Can I write sls for this?

Comment: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pip_state.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new "onedir" packages for Salt do not use the system Python, so the system package `python3-pyinotify` will be ignored.

Either install it from the CLI:

```bash
salt-pip install pyinotify
```

or via a state:

```yaml
pyinotify:
  pip.installed: []
```